# RStudio View() display nothing

Tags: rstudio

When I use RStudio to see the data by View() function, nothing displays in the table.
I have reinstalled the R-3.4.0 and RStudio 1.0.143, but this bug still exists.

[image: the picture for the problem]

Comment: Can you also supply the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0